# How to test nagios send_nsca with netcat

Tags: nagios, netcat

I am trying to write a unit test of `send_nsca` using `nc` but it is failing.

I want to start `nc` to listen to the nsca port and then use `send_ncsa` to send a message to that port.

In one terminal I am running:

```
nc -l 5667 -v
```

In the other:

```
echo -e "foo.example.com\ttest\t0\t0" | ./send_nsca -H localhost -p 5667 -c send_nsca.cfg
```

My `send_nsca.cfg` file only contains: `encryption_method=0`.

On the listening terminal I get:

```
Connection from 10.1.30.23 port 5667 [tcp/*] accepted
```

But nothing else. On the `send_nsca` side I get:

```
Error: Timeout after 10 seconds
```

Any ideas?

**EDIT:**

I recompiled the source and enabled DEBUG output:

```
Connected okay...
Error: Timeout after 10 seconds
Cleaned up encryption routines
```

From the code I see I am missing the initialization packet containing the IV and timestamp:

```
#ifdef DEBUG
    printf("Connected okay...\n");
#endif

/* read the initialization packet containing the IV and timestamp */
result=read_init_packet(sd);
if(result!=OK){
    printf("Error: Could not read init packet from server\n");
    close(sd);
    do_exit(STATE_CRITICAL);
        }

#ifdef DEBUG
    printf("Got init packet from server\n");
#endif
```

Is there any other way to test send_nsca without a full blown nagios installation?

Comment: Perform a TCPDUMP of a working connection first?  I don't know the `send_nsca` protocol, but are the server just sits there like a dead horse?  Does it not have any greetings,salutations, acknowledgements, or other messages the server must send as part of the protocol?  If you look at a working capture, you should be able to figure out what you need to make nc do.  Your other options is to actually use the source.  It should all be very clear in the source code about exactly what send_ncsa is sending and expecting.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need a "full blown nagios installation" to test send_nsca...

NSCA is an add-on, and is not part of Nagios core itself. It's packaged as a separate component in Debian/Ubuntu and CentOS (epel or repoforge), for example.

NSCA runs as a daemon or via inetd/xinetd. See the [NSCA setup docs](http://nagios.sourceforge.net/download/contrib/documentation/misc/NSCA_Setup.pdf) for more information about how to run it.

Also, there are several drop-in replacements for NSCA available; [NRDP](http://exchange.nagios.org/directory/Addons/Passive-Checks/NRDP--2D-Nagios-Remote-Data-Processor/details) and [NSCA-ng](https://wiki.icinga.org/display/howtos/NSCA-ng) may be of interest to you for testing.